# Does DOM size affect $("#id") performance?

Tags: jquery, performance, dom, jquery-selectors

I was wondering if the size of the DOM affects the performance for selecting elements by ID.

I was thinking to store content that is loaded via ajax in the DOM and hide it once it is not needed anymore. This way I could just show it if it is needed. This would of course bloat the DOM, so if it has a negative performance effect on selecting by ID I would not want to do it. (Since performance is what I am aiming for in the first place).

Comment: Well, I'm not a DOM core expert, but I think like any system, the more data you've to loop through the more time it takes to find it, even with indexed system, the index size increases the lookup time.

Comment: I would imagine under the hood, the jQuery selectors have to parse the entire dom for an ID so my gut would say yes, then again once the ID is found it has to go no further, so it would probably be more influenced by 'where' the ID is in the tree.

Comment: I don't know if it affects the selector performance (perhaps it is a hash table), you have to meassure that, but it will require more and more browser memory, so storing too much DOM is not an option either. You have to find the balance for your application and your DOM usage

Comment: You can use browser's local storage to store the loaded from AJAX data, if you want to minimize the HTTP requests

Comment: Probably not. `id`s are required to be unique, so they are a prime target for putting into a hashtable. Hashtables can exhibit severe performance issues in engineered scenarios (i.e. if you do it on purpose), but in general there should be no difference. However, don't listen to me: test it.

Comment: How many megabytes is the added content? and what is the target browser?

Comment: I would guess that it would, but unless your page is HUGE - we're talking several hundred kb of just HTML - then I don't think you'd see a noticeable performance drain.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the replies. I was thinking about localStorage too, but, since I have some data that needs to be kept in localStorage I was afraid to exceed the limit. (Although I guess it is not likely).
Does storing the html in a variable have a negative performance impact?